# java.net.NoRouteToHostException raised trying to reach non-existing hosts on the*same* subnet of the client

Tags: java, network-programming

I wrote a simple java tcp client. I specify the server ip address on the command line every time I run the client.

When there is no server listening on the specified ip address or the ip address doesn't exist, a SocketTimeoutException is raised. This is working fine for any ip address outside the subnet in which the client is running. If I specify a wrong server ip address *on the same* subnet of the client, a java.net.NoRouteToHostException is raised instead.

This is weird for me. Belonging both addresses to the same subnet there's absolutely no need to have an ip route in order to reach the server. This would be true if the server lives on a different subnet from the client and the host on which the client is running has no default gateway.

What I want is simply receive a SocketTimeoutException even for wrong addresses on the same subnet of the client (I mean addresses on which there is no listening server or non-existing addresses).

How can I obtain this behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. By the way in my opinion this exception is a little misleading, because it is raised although I have a default route.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between this two exceptions.

**1. NoRouteToHostException:**

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

**2. SocketTimeoutException**

> Signals that a timeout has occurred on a socket read or accept.

So, if you have `NoRouteToHostException`, this means that that address can't be reached (in your case it probably doesn't exist), and if you have `SocketTimeoutException` this address exists, but you can't connect to specific port (nothing listens there).

Comment: I got your point but in my case it's a little bit different. If I specify a not-existing server address out of client's subnet, a SocketTimeoutException is raised. If I specify another not-existing address in the same client's subnet, I have NoRouteToHostException. In both case the addresses don't exist but I get two different exceptions. The only difference is the address belonging or not to the client's subnet.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. NoRouteToHostException means exactly what it says. It refers to the local host's routing tables. It has nothing whatsoever to do with firewalls or routers. SocketTimeoutException does not occur when trying to connect. If nothing is listening, you get a ConnectException. -1

Comment: As you can see this is directly from [java api doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html)

Comment: The Java API documentation is wrong about NoRouteToHostException, and you are wrong about SocketTimeoutException: the Javadoc doesn't say anything about 'nothing listens there', as you did in your final paragraph, which you made up. See also the Javadoc for ConnectException.

Comment: You told "It has nothing whatsoever to do with firewalls or routers". Quoted text (from documentation): "Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down."???

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, you're not going to be able to wrap both of those conditions into one exception. The problem is that there's two separate things going on here.

For sending packets out of the local subnet, the system running your app will use the local gateway which sends it to the next router in the chain and so on until the destination network is reached. Because there's no one at the specified destination address, nothing will respond and you get a timeout exception.

For the local subnet, the system tries to directly connect to the destination address. This means it's going to first send out some sort of ARP request. Unfortunately there will be no response to this and the system won't know how to send out your packets, resulting in an "I can't find a way to send this out" error. aka, a NoRouteToHost exception.

The difference is that, in the first case, the system can send requests but in the second case cannot. That's why there's two separate errors.